# Stack and passing by reference

Tags: c, struct, scope, stack, pass-by-reference

Let's say I have this struct.

```
typedef struct Symbol {
    char* name;
    /* Other variables declared here... */
    struct Symbol *next;
}Symbol;
```

What I want to do is insert some of these **Symbol**s in a stack. Besides the other A.D.T. that these **Symbol**s will be inserted.
So for that reason, I created a struct of type `func` to handle my stack like so:

```
typedef struct func{
    Symbol* sym; 
    struct func* next
}func;
```

And declared a pointer to the stack `func* funcstack;` which will serve as my stack's **head**.

Now, the functions which handle the stack operations are as follows

```
/**
 * @brief
 */
func* push_func(func* head, Symbol* ret) {
    func* tmp = (func*)malloc(sizeof(func));
    if (!tmp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "push_func: Allocation error!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    tmp->sym = ret;
    tmp->next = head;
    head = tmp;
    return head;
}

/**
 * @brief
 */
func* pop_func(func* head, Symbol* ret) {
    if (!head) {
        printf("pop_func: Trying to pop from empty funcstack!!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    func* tmp = head;
    ret = head->sym;
    head = head->next;
    free(tmp);
    return head;
}


/**
 * @brief
 */
func* top_func(func* head, Symbol* ret) {
    if (!head) {
        printf("top_func: Trying to top from empty funcstack!!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else {
        ret = head->sym;
        return head;
    }
}
```

Up to this point, I want to clarify if my implementation is correct. Although, I think that something is missing for sure.

I call `push` like this:

```
Symbol* f = malloc(sizeof(Symbol));
f->name = strdup("Hello");
funcstack = push_func(funcstack, f);
```

During my implementation I call `top` and `pop` like so:

```
Symbol* f;
funcstack = top_func(funcstack, f);
funcstack = pop_func(funcstack, f);
```

And for testing purposes I've added a `printf("f->name = %s", f->name);` underneath this point. Theoretically speaking, at this point, `f` should be pointing to a **specific Symbol** since my stack **shouldn't** be empty at the point which is called. So I would expect my `printf()` to print something like this: `f->name = hello` but instead I get **garbage (f->name = �E�)**

Why is this happening? And how could I fix this? I think the answer lyies in `call-by-reference` and `call-by-value` which I fail to understand when handling self declared data types. I'm using **C** as my implementation language.

Comment: `ret = head->sym;` at `pop_func` and `top_func` is wrong. (call by value in C)

Comment: You aren't making any use of `ret` in `top_func` and `pop_func`.  You're just doing a local assignment which is discarded upon return.  If you wish to use `ret` to return something, then you need to assign to `*ret`.  So you need to add a level of indirection, so that it's a `Symbol **`, then pass the address of `f` when making your call.  Then the functions can assign to `*ret` and `f` will be updated in the caller.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY why? if i'm poping something from a function i want it to be the top element. and since `func` has a pointer to the symbol I want, i think it's correct.

Comment: read Tom Karzes's comment.

Comment: @TomKarzes Why would you need one more level of indirection ? Pass a `Symbol*` in order to get back a `Symbol`.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you Tom, for your answer. I've posted it as an answer to my question. It was really helpfull!

Comment: @Nelxiost Because the intent is not to do a structure assignment, but rather to return a pointer to the structure.  That's why it has to be a `Symbol **`, so it can return a `Symbol *`.  Doing a structure copy would make no sense here.

Comment: @TomKarzes, can you please answer this question with all the above information?

Comment: @TomKarzes My bad, I was thinking of some other kind of structure. Also, you should put that as an answer (as SilentMonk just said).

Comment: @SilentMonk Ok, I posted my original comment as an answer.

Comment: @Nelxiost Ok, I posted my original comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't making any use of `ret` in `top_func` and `pop_func`. You're just doing a local assignment which is discarded upon return. If you wish to use `ret` to return something, then you need to assign to `*ret`. So you need to add a level of indirection, so that it's a `Symbol **`, then pass the address of `f` when making your call. Then the functions can assign to `*ret` and `f` will be updated in the caller. –

Answer (score 0):

This is just a repost from @TomKarzes answer

You aren't making any use of ret in top_func and pop_func. You're just doing a local assignment which is discarded upon return. If you wish to use ret to return something, then you need to assign to *ret. So you need to add a level of indirection, so that it's a Symbol **, then pass the address of f when making your call. Then the functions can assign to *ret and f will be updated in the caller.